# Law of the unconscious Statistician for Higher Order Functions

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I was wondering about a property about this Theorem:

The LOTUS describes that:

$$E[g(x)] = \int g(x) f(x) dx$$

where f(x) is the pdf of some cts function. This also applies for the discrete case, but lets ignore it for now.

I am wondering about the case with composite functions...
ie, does the following case stay true?

$$E[h(g(x))] = \int h(g(x)) f(x) dx$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it does! I hope it is clear from the original definition replacing $g$ with $g\circ h(x)=g(h(x))$.

Comment: Yes that actually makes sense. Thank you